# Weird fullScreenCover and sheet behaviour in iOS 15

Tags: swiftui, ios15

I have some problem with presenting sheet, sheet that use Identifiable item binding and fullScreenCover.

Main issue is that:

1. I choose identifiable item, corresponding sheet appears
2. I close that sheet with swipe
3. After it's dismiss i open normal sheet
4. It open again identifiable item sheet content

Another weird behaviour is if I open fullScreenCover after dismissing sheet it's open sheet but with content of fullScreenCover

This never happens on iOS 14. I think that is states that responsible for presenting those views not have time to update

You can checkout [minimal gist](https://gist.github.com/drucelweisse/78f07fa044e5a1e52cb618d61f968787) reproduction or see it here

```
import SwiftUI



struct ContentView: View {

   enum Sheet: String, Identifiable {
     var id: String {
     rawValue
    }
     case one, two
   }

@State var isFullScreenPresented: Bool = false
@State var isSheetPresented: Bool = false
@State var isItemSheetPresented: Sheet?

var body: some View {
   VStack {
      HStack {
         Button(action: {isFullScreenPresented.toggle()}, label: {
            Text("fullScreen")
               .padding()
               .foregroundColor(.red)

               .background(Rectangle())
         })
         
         
         Button(action: {isSheetPresented.toggle()}, label: {
            Text("sheet")
               .padding()
               .foregroundColor(.red)

               .background(Rectangle())
         })

         
      }
      HStack {
         
         Button(action: {isItemSheetPresented = .one}, label: {
            Text("one")
               .padding()
               .foregroundColor(.red)
               .background(Rectangle())
         })
         
         Button(action: {isItemSheetPresented = .two}, label: {
            Text("two")
               .padding()
               .foregroundColor(.red)

               .background(Rectangle())
         })
      }
      
      HStack {
         Text(isFullScreenPresented.description)
         Text(isSheetPresented.description)
      }
      Text(isItemSheetPresented.debugDescription)
      Spacer()
   }
   .sheet(item: $isItemSheetPresented, onDismiss: {isItemSheetPresented = nil}, content: {item in
      Text(item.id)
   })
   .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetPresented, onDismiss: { isSheetPresented = false}, content: {
      Text("sheet")
   })
   .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isFullScreenPresented, onDismiss: {isFullScreenPresented = false }, content: {FullScreenContent()})
}
}

struct FullScreenContent: View {
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) var dismiss
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
     Button("close", action: {dismiss.wrappedValue.dismiss()})
     Spacer()
  }
}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn’t have multiple sheets attached to the same view. Attach them to the view that triggers them. Also, on the one that takes in item you should use the sheet that uses an item as a trigger.

Comment: well, this behaviour works even when they attached in other views but contained in one view hierarchy. About having multiple sheets attached to the same view: it's was fixed in iOS 14.5